# Why swagger is not showing colored json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger-ui

My swagger is showing the return json this way:

[image]

but i want show the json colored like this:

[image]

I dont found nothing about how to configure the color of json. Anyone can help-me?

Comment: Lots of libraries can provide a Swagger page. Which one are you using?

Comment: i'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen, Version=5.5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

i'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen also and i had the same issue.

In my case (ctrl + shift + r) solved my problem in chrome. This combination reloads the page with ignoring cached content.

I think problem causing from cache, so clearing cache and reloading page is the solution for me.

Hope this helps.