# My Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger have a problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API to convert currencies based on a local database. I create my controller, serive, repository and even though I can perform the query in the database I don't get the same result via API.I've already spent a few hours trying to solve this and nothing seems to work, here's the print.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lufi1.png). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653989/swagger-is-endlessly-loading-but-never-getting-the-data-asp-net-core) case not is equals my problem because my swagger loads. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489062/why-swagger-is-not-showing-colored-json) case not is equal my problem because i don't care about swagger color.

My controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
public class CurrencyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{code}")]
    public ObjectResult GetByCode([FromServices] CurrencyReadRepository repository, string code)
    {
        return Ok(repository.GetCurrency(code));
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try on StartUp.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<CurrencyReadRepository>();
```

Comment: OMG, I'm very noob, I had already done repository dependency injection but I forgot that the reads were moved to another repository. Thanks a lot my friend.

Comment: @JorgeJudas No problem, these things happen sometimes.